# How to get Spring property with embedded property variable as a literal

Tags: spring, application.properties

I currently have a Spring `application.properties` with 2 properties defined as follows:

```
validator.url=http://location.com/${domain}/${family}
query.validator.url=${validator.url}
```

Currently my application resolves `query.validator.url` to be `${validator.url}`
is there anyway that I can have it resolve to the same value as `validator.url` which is `http://location.com/${domain}/${family}`

Note: `${domain}` and `${family}` don't resolve, they are handled in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
validator.url=http://location.com/#{'$'}{domain}/#{'$'}{family}
query.validator.url=${validator.url}
```

Both `validator.url` and `query.validator.url` will resolve to `http://location.com/${domain}/${family}`

Alternatively, you can create a property for the `$`, which you can then use inside `validator.url`, e.g.:

```
var=$
validator.url=http://location.com/${var}{domain}/${var}{family}
```

There's an issue regarding this on [Spring's JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4953)

Comment: Didn't quite work.  `query.validator.url` resolved to `http://location.com/#{'$'}{domain}/#{'$'}{family}`

Comment: That's odd, I ran it on my end and it resolved just fine when I used `@Value`. How about the second solution?

Comment: I'll have to get back to this later.  Thanks for that JIRA link though.